# System error: libfreerdp.codec1.1 needs to be reinstalled

Tags: package-management

I recently keep getting a system error that says:

```
libfreerdp.codec1.1 needs to be reinstalled.
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the package? Or don't you know which packet it is? What did you do to find out?

Comment: See if this helps: `sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-dev` ...

Comment: This wht happened after trying to install liffreerdp-devE: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?